# Print values of ArrayList instead of classname

Tags: c#, arraylist, console.writeline

I'd like to print all ten random generated points for each object in the ArrayList AL.

```
public class Point
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    
        public Point(int x, int y)
        {
            x = this.x;
            y = this.y;
        }
        
    }    

public class ArrayListTest
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArrayList AL = new ArrayList();
            Random Rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                Point p = new Point(Rnd.Next(50), Rnd.Next(50));
                AL.Add(p);            
            }
    
        PrintValues(AL);
        }
    
        public static void PrintValues(IEnumerable myList)
        {
            
            foreach (Object obj in myList)
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ", obj);
        }
    }
```

Output on console:

```
Point 
Point 
Point 
Point 
Point 
Point 
Point 
Point 
Point 
Point
```

My Problem is, that the classname of the object printed and not the values of the objects.
I am using .NET Framework v4.8

Comment: First of all, do not use an ArrayList, use a List<Point>. Secondly, override ToString() to print the x and y

Comment: Please show us your `Point` class, or confirm that you are using `System.Drawing.Point`. Your code works fine if using `System.Drawing.Point`.

Comment: Alternatively to answers given, you could consider using [Point Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point?view=netframework-4.8) instead of your own Point class.

Comment: You have your X and Y  assignments in the constructor going in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Aside: I recommend that you don't define your own class called `Point`. It's likely to conflict with a built-in class and cause confusion. You should give your class a different name.)

So, what happens when you do `Console.WriteLine(object obj)` is that inside `Console.WriteLine()` it ends up calling `object.ToString()` to determine the string to write.

By default, if you don't write your own implementation of `ToString()`, it will return the name of the class - this is why you are seeing `Point` in the output.

Since you are writing your own `Point` class, you can override its `ToString()` to return a formatted string. This is the best solution.

Assuming that your `Point` class has X and Y values, you can do that by adding the following to the class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"X={x}, Y={y}";
}
```

If you didn't want to do this (or supposing it was a third-party class that you couldn't change), you would have to format the string explicitly before passing it to `Console.WriteLine()`.

Unfortunately, because you are using `ArrayList`, you end up with only an `object` - so in order to format it you will need to cast it to the correct type in order to get at its X and Y values:

```
foreach (Object obj in myList)
{
    Point p = (Point)obj;
    Console.WriteLine("X={0}, Y={1}", p.x, p.y);
}
```

Or you can take advantage of the fact that a `foreach` for an `IEnumerable` will do the cast for you if you declare the loop variable as the correct type:

```
foreach (Point p in myList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("X={0}, Y={1}", p.x, p.x);
}
```

However, much better is to use `List<Point>` rather than an `ArrayList` - then the elements will be of type `Point`:

```
static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Point> AL  = new List<Point>();
        Random      Rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Point p = new Point(Rnd.Next(50), Rnd.Next(50));
            AL.Add(p);
        }

        PrintValues(AL);
    }

    public static void PrintValues(IEnumerable<Point> myList)
    {
        foreach (var p in myList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("X={0}, Y={1}", p.x, p.x);
        }
    }
}
```

As a final note, you might want to consider using the `System.Drawing.Point` or `System.Windows.Point` struct rather than rolling your own `Point` class.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using generic collections, which would be more ideal here.  But because you are not, you are working with `object`s.  The default `ToString` implementation on an object will return the name of the object.  You'll need to cast your object back to a `Point` type  to work with it.

This is one way to cast the object back to a point

```
public static void PrintValues(IEnumerable myList)
{
    
    foreach (var point in myList.Cast<Point>())
        Console.WriteLine($"{obj.X} {obj.Y}");
}
```

Comment: @Fildor Point class is added in the question.